# can i use i18n key name with spaces and some special characters?

Tags: java, internationalization, aem

I want to use the JSTL tags with i18n.

In creation of the i18n key value pair, **can i use i18n key name with spaces and some special characters?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The key in the i18n dictionary is the English string. An example from the AEM Maven Archetype:

The i18n French dictionary at `/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/demosite/i18n/fr.xml`:

```
<copyright
    jcr:mixinTypes="[sling:Message]"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:folder"
    sling:key="&amp;copy; {0} AEM Demo Site. All rights reserved."
    sling:message="&amp;copy; {0} AEM Demo Site. Tous droits réservés."/>
```

And the string being utilized at `/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/demosite/components/structure/page/partials/main.html`:

```
<footer class="page__footer">
    <p class="page__copyright">${"&copy; {0} AEM Demo Site. All rights reserved." @ i18n, format=main.year, context='html'}</p>
</footer>
```